# Capture screen shot as video and display live but mirrored?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to develop a `c#` windows form application that captures part of the screen and display it's mirror live **video like** in the windows form picturebox. 
The problem that I'm facing is that when I set the form's `visibility=false` to capture part of the screen without capturing the form itself, then back to form `visibility=true`, I get this flickering mirrored and not mirrored picture displaying in the picturebox. 
My issue is that I'm trying to mirror any video playing on what ever application i.e: `youtube`, `windows media player` or `any other application` by capturing multiple screenshots and displaying them in a picture box so that when the video is playing and the application is running in front of it, the user see's a mirror of whatever is playing behind the form live. 
How do I stop the flickering and make this like video like live stream like of the back video but mirrored as the video is playing. Thank you in advance

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Mirror
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region Form Design and Controls

        private void btnFlip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             timer1.Start();
        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height);
             this.Visible = false;
             using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap))
             {
                  g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, myBitmap.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
             }
             if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
             {
                    pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
                    this.pictureBox1.Image = myBitmap;
                    pictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipY);

                    GC.Collect();

               }

               this.Visible = true;
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```